# apply filter without join on custom column in sales order grid in magento 2

Tags: custom, filter, column

i have custom column in sales order grid and want to apply filter on this .

When i apply filter then generate log `unknown column my_custom_column is not exist`

My Custom Column is not exits in any table of the column .

my code is :

**view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="sales_order_columns">
          <column name="my_custom_column" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerDetail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Detail</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
          </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```

**Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerDetail.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class CustomerDetail extends Column
{
    /**
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $groupsName=array(
            '0'=>'NOT LOGGED IN',
            '1'=>'General',
            '2'=>'Wholesale',
            '3'=>'Retailer',
            '999'=>'Seller'
        );
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items)  {
                $items['my_custom_column']='<b>Customer Name :</b> ' .$items['customer_name'].'<br><br><b>Email :</b>' .$items['customer_email'].'<br><br><b>Group :</b>' .$groupsName[$items['customer_group']];
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

It work good But i want to apply filter own my custom column that is not exist in any table column .

Comment: This solution worked for me - https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-columns-along-with-filters-to-product-grid-in-admin-magento-2/

Comment: @Ranganathan  let me check please

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-columns-along-with-filters-to-product-grid-in-admin-magento-2/
this solution is not for me because i say my custom attribute is not exist in any table on which we use join .

Comment: But i cannot see `my_custom_column` in your code

Comment: @Ranganathan check question again i update my question . 

actually "my_custom_column" mean "customer_detail" 

I update check please

Comment: Yes I noticed now....Will let you know once i got solution

Comment: This is not possible....Magento grid search will build a query to find data in table...In above question you created a grid column without database column. Try to create a custom column in sales_order_grid table and save the value what you want to display

Comment: No my requirement is should not make any column in database .

if make column then use observers for save value in database .

Comment: Yes, That is a solution for this I think...May be someone know for any solution for this..Lets wait for a luck.